# Parallel + Stream + Encryption ... c# supposed to work

Tags: c#, encryption, parallel-processing

Something very weird occur in my code.

If i create a simple for without parallel my code working fine.

But when I add Parallel.For it's no more working.

The problem is when it's rebuild the binary are not the same with the Parallel For but it's the same with the normal For ...

I create a sample for the example.

Essentially, the code only read a file, save it in chunck. 
After "Simulate upload", just rebuild the file with the same Key and IV.

Like i said in the normal For everything working fine.

```
// Decryption


public static byte[] DecryptBinaryFromBytes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
      // Check arguments. 
      if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
      if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
      if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");



      // Create an RijndaelManaged object 
      // with the specified key and IV. 
      using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
      {
        rijAlg.Key = Key;
        rijAlg.IV = IV;

        // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

        // Create the streams used for decryption. 
        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
          using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
          {
            csDecrypt.Write(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);
            csDecrypt.Close();
          }
          return msDecrypt.ToArray();
        }
      }
    }

// Encryption



    public static byte[] EncryptBinary(byte[] binary, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
          // Check arguments. 
          if (binary == null || binary.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Binary");
          if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
          if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
          byte[] encrypted;
          // Create an RijndaelManaged object 
          // with the specified key and IV. 
          using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
          {
            rijAlg.Key = Key;
            rijAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption. 
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
              using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
              {

                using (BinaryWriter swEncrypt = new BinaryWriter(csEncrypt))
                {

                  //Write all data to the stream.
                  swEncrypt.Write(binary);
                }
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
              }
            }
          }


          // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream. 
          return encrypted;

        }


// Rebuild the file


     static void RebuildFile(string directory, string file, int totalParts)
            {
              string finalName = string.Concat(directory, file);

              using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(finalName, FileMode.Append))
              {
                for (int i = 0; i < totalParts; i++)
                {
                  string fileName = $"{i.ToString("00000")}-{file}";
                  string path = Path.Combine(directory, fileName);
                  byte[] binary = DecryptBinaryFromBytes(File.ReadAllBytes(path), key, iv); 
                  fs.Write(binary, 0, binary.Length);              
                }
                fs.Close();
              }

            }


 // Simulate upload       




 static void SimulateUpload(string filePath, byte[] binary)
        {
          binary = EncryptBinary(binary,key, iv); 

          using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append))
          {
            fs.Write(binary, 0, binary.Length);
          }
        }



 // variable declaration





      static byte[] key;
           static byte[] iv;



// The main method


 static void Main(string[] args)
            {
              key = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray().Concat(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray()).ToArray();
              iv = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();

              string inputFile = @"C:\temp\Fonctionnement-FR.docx";
              string directory = @"C:\temp\uploads\";
              const long BUFFER_SIZE = 524288;
              byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

              FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(inputFile);
              long totalBytes = fInfo.Length;
              double estimateTotalChuck = Math.Ceiling((totalBytes / BUFFER_SIZE) + 0.5);
              int totalParts = (int)estimateTotalChuck;
              string fileName = Path.GetFileName(inputFile);
              string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(inputFile);

             // This one is Working
                for (int idx=0;idx<totalParts; idx++)
              {
                using (Stream input = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                  using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
                  {

                    long startPosition = (idx * BUFFER_SIZE);
                    long maxPosition = startPosition + BUFFER_SIZE;
                    int maxBufferRead = (int)BUFFER_SIZE;
                    input.Seek(startPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    if (maxPosition > totalBytes)
                    {
                      maxBufferRead = (int)(totalBytes - startPosition);
                    }
                    input.Read(buffer, 0, maxBufferRead);
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, maxBufferRead);

                    SimulateUpload(string.Concat(directory, $"{idx.ToString("00000")}-{fileName}"), output.ToArray());

                    //  upFile = UploadSingleFile(endPoint, new FileArgs(output.ToArray(), fileName, fileExtension, idx, totalParts), handShake, chunkSize, idx, totalParts, fileIdentifier);

                  }
                }

              }


    // This one is not working
 Parallel.For(0, (int)estimateTotalChuck, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, idx =>

      {
        using (Stream input = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
          using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
          {

            long startPosition = (idx * BUFFER_SIZE);
            long maxPosition = startPosition + BUFFER_SIZE;
            int maxBufferRead = (int)BUFFER_SIZE;
            input.Seek(startPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            if (maxPosition > totalBytes)
            {
              maxBufferRead = (int)(totalBytes - startPosition);
            }
            input.Read(buffer, 0, maxBufferRead);
            output.Write(buffer, 0, maxBufferRead);

            SimulateUpload(string.Concat(directory, $"{idx.ToString("00000")}-{fileName}"), output.ToArray());

            //  upFile = UploadSingleFile(endPoint, new FileArgs(output.ToArray(), fileName, fileExtension, idx, totalParts), handShake, chunkSize, idx, totalParts, fileIdentifier);

          }
        }

      });

          RebuildFile(directory, fileName, totalParts);

        }
```

Comment: where are things like `buffer` defined? if you have multiple threads updating and reading from the same buffer in parallel; yeah, that's going to fail spectacularly

Comment: Additionally to what Marc said: Whatever parallel task finishes first with its computation/processing, will write first to the target file. There is no particular order in which the tasks will finish, as it depends on environmental factors such as your specific hardware configuration, the overall load on the system/CPU, latencies introduced by other system components (such as the I/O sub system), etc... The parallel version of your code needs to make sure that the file data is written in correct order.

Comment: @elgonzo i know that, it's the reason i create a "SimulateUpload" where I passe the idx variable who is supposed to be the right "part" of the file. After that i rebuild the file in the correct order ...

Comment: @MarcGravell the "buffer" are defined at the external of the foreach ... maybe my mistake is there ... i will try to correct that.

Comment: @MarcGravell There we go ... a stupid mistake. Was the declaration of my Buffer. Please write it as an answer ... and i will give your the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you switch to parallel code, you need to be **acutely** aware of where all locals are declared; anything declared outside the parallel region will be shared by *all the parallel threads*. In this case, it looks like `buffer` is a key contender, and since that is the primary data exchange mechanism, it would be entirely expected that if multiple threads are reading and writing to `buffer` concurrently, that they're all virtually guaranteed to trip over each-other.

But: check all the other locals too! If in doubt: move the code that runs in parallel to a **separate method**. It is hard to trip over shared locals in that scenario. Note that for ref-type parameters (such as `byte[]`), you'd also need to ensure that the *objects* are separate - separate locals to the same object has the same problem.